# array_agg function in postgres, when used in java does not return any record/data?

Tags: java, postgresql, array-agg

I have a query like this

```
select sender_id, ARRAY_AGG(receiver_id) as receiver_id from senderTbl group by sender_id
```

When I execute this query in **pgAdmin** it works well and returns the record like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMmex.png)
But when called from java code it doesn't work

```
String query = "select sender_id, ARRAY_AGG(receiver_id) as receiver_id from senderTbl group by sender_id"
Query q = session.createSQLQuery(query);
 List li = new LinkedList();
 li = q.list();
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: No error, It just returns 0 records

Comment: The you are probably connecting to a different database or server

Comment: Noo :), have also checked that

Comment: I somehow did it, Had to change receiver_id dataType from integer to string in postgres and used string_agg function. Then it worked. Array_agg() did not worked with string values also.